# Windows phone home button press functionality

Tags: windows-phone-8

In Wp8, if I am navigating through the App, and next I press the home button(Windows icon) on the phone.
What should be the screen that I should be navigated to when I then start my app again, should the app start from the resumed screen or the first landing screen of the app.

Also is the fast app resume, the feature to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

If you press the home button as you said, your app will go to the background, so when you resume it, it will open to the page you were at last time. Resuming a app, is as normal as it can, neither slow nor fast.

Comment: Don't forget to say that you can implement fast resume for increase  user's experience :)